# Why doesn't $value = $_POST['businessname']; read the name from the input form?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have fixed the error: I had to put @ sign before $_Post['businessname']
The correct syntax is:
    $value = @$_POST['businessname'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO checkout (businessname) VALUES ('$value')";

businessname is a name inside the input of the form:

In mysql database in phpMyAdmin I have a database called database_db which contains a table called checkout, that table has a field/name (in my mysql it is "Name" instead of the "Field") called "businessname".

Inside my checkout_form.php which is connected to my checkout.php file through the following line:

```
<form action="checkout_form.php" class="well first-form" action="<?php echo SITE_URL; ? >secured/checkout" id="questionnaireForm" name="sendMsg" novalidate="" method="post">
```

I have the following code:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database_db');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$connection){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

if(!$db_selected){
die('Can\'t use ' .DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysqli_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

$value = $_POST['businessname'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO checkout (businessname) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysqli_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}
```

When I run the checkout_form.php in my browser I get the first line:
    Connected successfully
And then I get the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: businessname in C:\wamp\www\folder\checkout_form.php on line 22

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in  C:\wamp\www\folder\checkout_form.php on line 25

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp\www\folder\checkout_form.php on line 26
```

Why do I get those errors?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injections attacks.  It's very important to sanitize input you read from the browser before using it in queries.

Comment: The `<form>` tag doesn't tell us much. What does the `<input>` tag look like?

Comment: @ceejayoz this is the input tag: 
    <input class="form-control" name="businessname" id="business-name" type="text" placeholder="Business Name" required="" data-validation-required-message=" " />

Surreal Dreams what do you mean by "It's very important to sanitize input you read from the browser before using it in queries"?

Comment: @Arwen For future reference, please edit your question to add more details... It's far easier to format legibly.

Comment: @Arwen your form tag as two action params, it only supports one. It would help if you posted the input in the form for businessname, or the entire form. Guessing you just have a typo in there but hard to see without the code.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @JimL thank you for noticing, I fixed the error in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the errors we need to pass the correct parameters to the functions being called.

`mysqli_query` takes two parameters when using the procedural version while `mysqli_error` takes one

Try:

```
if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
```

Also your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection...

Comment: thank you, it worked. I did not know I had to pass $connections and was very confused. I still cannon understand why it considers my "businessname" to be undefined and please explain what do you mean by SQL injections? And how can I prevent it?

Comment: I just found an article on it: https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/

Comment: Can you update your question with the full form HTML?

Comment: Overachiever the form is huge, I can provide portion of it but how would that help?

Comment: Alright so is the error happening after you press the submit button or when you just go to the page with the form on it.

Comment: Theres a good chance that your INSERT logic is always running, even when the form isn't submitted if you have the INSERT logic in the same file.  In that case you'll want to wrap that logic with something like `if(isset($_POST['businessname'])){/**INSERT LOGIC*/}`

Comment: Overachiever, when I go on the page that contains the html for the form with jquery validation, the form works fine. What gives me the error is the .php file that contains mysqli where I make the connection between the form and the database. I have fixed the errors that required parameters, the only error left is the one with the "businessname".

Comment: What does the submit button look like, is it actually submitting the form or is it just redirecting to checkout_form.php, and update your question with your jquery validation and the submit button code.

Answer (score 0):

This code has a few problems:

1. **General**: It is vulnerable to injection attacks (consider using prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
2. **The PHP Notice**: Your post array does not contain a businessname field. This could either be because you have not yet received a post response (you can check for that using isset) or the field is named different in the html input tag.
3. **The two warnings**: You need to pass a connection identifier (as Overacheiver mentions) to the procedural mysqli calls.